# Pass ViewData to ActionResult using RedirectToAction in C# ASP.NET MVC Pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, design-patterns, properties

I have a form that once submitted will have some complex routing based on what is entered in combination with server side calculaitons. I want to pass data that is collected from the first form to second form via RedirectToAction.

At first I thought I could perform a RedirectToAction to pass the data via a POST method cleanly, but it appears there is no easy way to do this. Reading more I want to see if there is some easy way I can just pass a Hashtable or ViewData through an RedirectToAction to the proper ActionResult and just read the variables but that is proving more challenging than I thought.

Here is a simplified version of what I am trying it.

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET","POST")]
public ActionResult Step8(int id = 0, Hashtable FormValues = null) {

    // was this a redirect back to us?
    if (FormValues != null && FormValues.Count > 0) {
        if (FormValues.ContainsKey("title") && FormValues["title"] != null) {
            string _title = FormValues["title"].ToString();
        }
    }
    // the form in thie view redirects to Step9
    return View(); 
}

[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public ActionResult Step9(int id = 0) {
    bool issue_found = true;

    if(issue_found){
        // hypothetical issue found, back to previous step
        Hashtable _FormValues = new Hashtable();
        _FormValues.Add("title", "My Title");
        _FormValues.Add("product", "My thing");
        return this.RedirectToAction("Step8", _FormValues);
    }else{
        // .. do stuff
        return View();
    }   
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I pass this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach was more complicated then it needed to be. *TempData* survives a *Redirect* so that is what I did. Here is a working solution:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET","POST")]
public ActionResult Step8(int id = 0) {

    string _product = "";
    string _title = "";

    // was this a redirect back to us?
    try {
        if (TempData != null) {
            if (TempData.ContainsKey("product") && TempData["product"] != null) {
                _product = TempData["product"].ToString();
            }
            if (TempData.ContainsKey("title") && TempData["title"] != null) {
                _title = TempData["title"].ToString();
            }
        }
    } catch {}

    // The form in this view performs a POST to Step9
    return View(); 
}

[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public ActionResult Step9(int id = 0) {
    bool issue_found = true;

    if(issue_found){
        // hypothetical issue found, back to previous step

        TempData["title"] = "My Title";
        TempData["product"] = "My thing";
        return this.RedirectToAction("Step8");
    }else{
        // .. do stuff
        return View();
    }   
}
```